# how to implement the un bypassed SSL pinning in android

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, android-security

I am developing a finance app where I have implemented the SSL pinning. My software testing team bypassed my SSL pinning approach. How can I implement the complex SSL Pinning method in android?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some solutions:

- Anti repack your apk: because if a hacker want to bypass SSL pinning, he have to repack your apk using apktool. You can do that by check your apk signature, if not match, exit your app.
- Move your code of SSL pining to NDK and build .so lib to use, hacker may be harder to modify .so file to bypass.

Answer (score 0):

General speaking, there's two ways to bypass SSL pining:

- Hooking to avoid SSL check or changing the result i.e., the return
  value of checker function. To this aim Frida is a popular tool.
- Certificate-related data (like public key) manipulation is application assets or in the application code

[Here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/iOS-SSL-certificate-pinning-bypassing), you can find more explanation about above methods.

To defeat against aforementioned attacks, one way is code/string obfuscation.